# Display the users wanted instagram photo from URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a website/page where the user can display their wanted Instagram photo from a URL, I'm still learning, and I already have a little start here:

HTML:

```html
<img id="myImage" />
<input id="imageUrl" type="text" value="https://www.instagram.com/p/CUVZs0YP6kl/" placeholder="placeholder">
<button id="loadButton">Load image</button>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loadButton').on('click',function(){
            $("#loadButton")[0].play();
        });
        $('#loadButton')[0].click();

    });
</script>
```

JavaScript:

```js
const imageFrame = document.getElementById('myImage');
const imageUrlInput = document.getElementById('imageUrl');
const loadButton = document.getElementById('loadButton');

loadButton.addEventListener('click', loadImage);

function loadImage() {
    imageFrame.src = imageUrlInput.value;
}
```

But it doesn't display the image, and I want to hide the "https://www.instagram.com/p/" so the user would only have to type the "CUVZs0YP6kl" part of the link in the box to get the image displayed on the page; I don't know how I would do that in JavaScript, so I need some help.

Comment: Why are you using both jQuery and native JS methods for updating/accessing the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

Add a string:

```js
const imageFrame = document.getElementById('myImage');
const imageUrlInput = document.getElementById('imageUrl');
const loadButton = document.getElementById('loadButton');

loadButton.addEventListener('click', loadImage);

function loadImage() {
    let instaUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/p/" + imageUrlInput.value + "/";
    imageFrame.src = instaUrl;
}
```

```html
<img id="myImage" src="" alt="Image will show here..." /><br>
<input id="imageUrl" type="text" value="CUVZs0YP6kl" placeholder="URL">
<button id="loadButton">Load image</button>
```

Also, <kbd>https:​//www.instagram.com/p/CUVZs0YP6kl/</kbd> is an HTML page displaying the image.

Not a valid image MIME type.

If you want to show the page, you can use `iframe`, `object` or `embed`:

```js
const imageFrame = document.getElementById('myImage');
const imageUrlInput = document.getElementById('imageUrl');
const loadButton = document.getElementById('loadButton');

loadButton.addEventListener('click', loadImage);

function loadImage() {
    let instaUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/p/" + imageUrlInput.value + "/";
    imageFrame.src = instaUrl;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="myImage" src=""></iframe><br>
<input id="imageUrl" type="text" value="CUVZs0YP6kl" placeholder="URL">
<button id="loadButton">Load image</button>
```

Or `object`:

```js
const imageFrame = document.getElementById('myImage');
const imageUrlInput = document.getElementById('imageUrl');
const loadButton = document.getElementById('loadButton');

loadButton.addEventListener('click', loadImage);

function loadImage() {
    let instaUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/p/" + imageUrlInput.value + "/";
    imageFrame.data = instaUrl;
}
```

```html
<object id="myImage" type="text/html" data=""></object><br>
<input id="imageUrl" type="text" value="CUVZs0YP6kl" placeholder="URL">
<button id="loadButton">Load image</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, i will look at those! Is there a way to only fetch the image from https:​//www.instagram.com/p/CUVZs0YP6kl/ to display it?

Comment: Yes, but it is not a fixed URL. https://instagram.ffxe1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/243127526_912981776006845_5513726439901945237_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.ffxe1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=xPxmf040BQAAX8_i4yI&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=a17a9fa93caf155ee21e92f90e157416&oe=618D13BD&_nc_sid=83d603